# 100mF Tantalum Capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, tantalum

I was looking at a circuit online when happen that both in schematic and on the board I saw this tantalum capacitor with a value of 100mF.

Now 100mF are 100000uF, It looks small for having such a capacitance?

A part from the fact that I cannot find any type of such capacitor online, would be possible?

[image]

[image]

I mean the yellow one there is 103nF...

[image]

Comment: Before the Greek alphabet was invented, we used mf to mean microfarad - millifarads were impossibly huge at the time.

Comment: @PeterBennett lol :DD

Comment: @PeterBennett Soda can sized capacitors LOL

Comment: @PeterBennett Or MF, which didn't mean megafarad.

Comment: A 100mF cap, even a low voltage one, would be at least the size of a milk crate. Such a huge...block...of tantalum. *drools*

Comment: @DKNguyen https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/KEMET/FGH0H104ZF?qs=sGAEpiMZZMukHu%252BjC5l7YfEq5W2hefEsb%252BLGo89nus0%3D

well actually there are supercaps with those values and they don't looks like a soda can

Comment: @Ken90 Those aren't tantalum though.

Comment: yeah of course :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They used to use mF for microFarads before \$\mu\$F became the de facto standard.

The board shown looks new enough that it should use \$\mu\$F though, so it's probably someone just doing things the wrong way, not everyone follows the rules (two resistors in one hole looks dodgy as well).

Most likely 100\$\mu\$F @ 10V from what I can see of the markings and the size of it.

Comment: My understanding is this was because older printing machines had an 'm' but not a 'μ'.

Comment: @DKNguyen Well maybe, but Greek characters have been available in print for at least 500 years, I've seen old resistors using \$\Omega\$, and they used mmF for picoFarads when there was a 'p' available. They also could have used 'uF', like many keyboard users tend to do. Not sure if there's a definitive reason for it all.

Comment: I think there might have been some reasoning like the u might looked like a rubbed off zero or something like that. Unsure.

Comment: m in [Windows Symbol font](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f0/c8/67/f0c8677dac1c509edab5eda18cda6f03.gif) is µ, so when files are converted and the font ends up missing, µ becomes m. Another common strangeness is Ω becoming W.

Answer (score 4):

Someone couldn't have been bothered to google "greek mu letter" and copy-paste it into the component properties in their EDA software, that's all there's to it.

Or, perhaps said EDA software - likely costing very good money - was broken by design and wasn't Unicode capable.

No, this was not done in KiCad, because KiCad's font looked quite differently until very recently, and because - surprise, surprise - it actually supported Greek alphabet just fine for quite some time now.